# iPhone - Http Post : send a value to a web xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, http-post

i know there are a lot of questions about this but none seems to work for what I want to do. I want to change the value of a tag so let's say i have this file :

```
</Courbe>
<tempset>140</tempset>
</Courbe>
```

I want my http post request to change this value. How do I do this?

I have already tried something like that :

```
- (IBAction)changeTemp:(id)sender 
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://207.134.145.16:50001/Courbe.xml"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *xmlString = @"<tempset>137</tempset>";

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Is it something like this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you called `-start` or `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`? (see [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: No as this is in a button, maybe I should edit it. But I shouldn't have to call it right?

Comment: The code above only creates a connection object, but doesn't begin the request/response transaction.

Comment: So if i use this [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; it should start?

Comment: Yes `+initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` will world also. Read the whole section on `NSURLConnection`. You will need to setup the proper `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url encode the xmlString, then:

```
NSData *postData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

To send, use something like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

Prior to iOS5, you can send asynchronously this way:

```
// make the request and an NSURLConnection with a delegate
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

// create a property to hold the response data, then implement the delegate methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [responseData release];
    [textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: This might have been good, but i forgot to mention that i'm developing for 4.0 my bad +1 for trying though! thanks

Comment: @BenLefebvre, it seemed the original point of your question was how to set the body of the post.  That's demonstrated in the first few lines of code in my answer.  How to send the request is a different question.  I'll edit my answer to include iOS<5.

Comment: After some tries, i'm able to get the request working..but I don't know how i can update the value in my xml file.

Comment: So if I understand: the file is remote, and you have a local copy?  You read the local copy, post a change via http, and then want to update the local.  Do I have that right?  It might be a new SO question.  Can you ask and post a link?  (My first thought, btw, if I have the question right and if the file is small-ish, would be to have the web service answer the modified file.  You could just replace your local copy.  Otherwise, there are a few client side solutions for writing xml.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15015/discussion-between-danh-and-ben-lefebvre)